# QTKit: Analog for VideoContext for the sound

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, qtkit

I am writing a simple application for streaming video over the network, using a slightly different from the ordinary "H.264 over RTP" approach (i am using my own codecs).

To achieve this, i need raw frames and raw audio samples that QTMovie, when playing back a movie, implicitly sends to QTMovieView.

The most common way to retrieve raw video frames is to use VisualContext - and then, using a display link callback, i "generate" a CVPixelBufferRef, using this VisualContext. So i am getting frames with some frequency that is synchronized with my current refresh rate (not that i need this synchronization - i only need to have a "stream" of frames that i can transmit over the network - but CoreVideo Programming Guide and most Apple samples related to video promote this approach).

The first problem i have faced with - is when i attach a VisualContext to a QTMovie, the picture can't be rendered onto the QTMovieView anymore. I don't know why does this happen (i guess it's related to the idea of GWorld and the rendering being "detached" from it when i attach VisualContext). Ok, at least i have frames, which i could render onto a simple NSView (though this sounds wrong, and performance-unfriendly. Am i doing it right?)

What about the sound, i have no idea what to do. I need to get raw samples of sound as the movie being played (ideally - something similar to what QTCaptureDecompressedAudioOutput returns in its callback). 
I have prepared myself to delving into deprecated Carbon QuickTime APIs, if there is no other way. But I don't know even where to start. Should i use the same CoreVideo Display link and periodically retrieve sound somehow? Should i get QTDataReference and locate the sound frames manually?

I am actually a beginner with programming video and audio services. If you could share some experience i would REALLY appreciate any idea you could share with me :)

Thank you,
James

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but is there any particular reason that keeps you from using QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput and QTCaptureDecompressedAudioOutput? They should provide you with the sample buffers you need in the delegate callbacks.